# iOS iPad design issues

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, ios-app, ipad

I'm using the iPad app 1.2.0.140. I have a few design/layout things that came to my mind:

- The about page hasn't a lot of content. Maybe it makes sense to display the about page in a popup similar to Achievements or Inbox.
- The sites menu item on the left has no focus marker (the red bar). Is that on purpose?
- The sites and pinned sites edit popup are different from the achievements/inbox popups (white top bar instead of a blue one). Will those be streamlined?
- Sometimes the profile top tags and top communities boxes have different height (couldn't reproduce this). 
  [image]

Comment: Looking at the screenshot attached, are you referring to the top tags/top communities top alignment, or their actual heights?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky I mean the different heights, however I'm not sure how to reproduce that. I'll accept your answer and create a new issue in case I ever get that problem again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have addressed your first three bullet points in beta version 1.2.0.141.

- Switched the about screen to be modal; this looks better and prevents the user from losing their current context
- The sites menu selection state (red bar) should now display correctly.
- The style for these popups will now be consistent (ended up going with the blue bar for all of them).

I'll take a look at the fourth point, but we should probably open a separate issue to help track it down.

Comment: New popups are looking great!